# Создание строк кодом С#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как используя код С# создавать строки вместо необходимости писать через XAML `<RowDefinition/>` огромное ~400 раз?

```
<Window x:Class="Proj1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    
    xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Main Window" Height="450" Width="800">


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment ="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
            <Menu IsMainMenu="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="New"/>
            </Menu>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid Height="1000" Width="1000" ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1111">

                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем вам `<RowDefinition/> огромное количество раз раз` ? Может, вам что то типа DataGrid нужно тогда?

Comment: Примерно [так](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/).

Comment: Это делается через привязку к коллекции `ItemsControl` и задание шаблона для строки. Опишите подробнее, какая у вас задача?

Comment: @tym32167, микротоновое фортепиано, по 53 клавиши на октаву, октав 7(+2) соответственно ~400 клавиш всего, на каждый нумерованный на рисунке прямоугольник примерно 1 кнопка

Comment: @aeopt, комментарий выше. +В левой части будет надо будет рисовать прямоугольники. Думаю разделить на ещё меньше части и там через `Canvas` сделать

Comment: 7 октав по 53 клавиши, это 371 прямоугольник, судя по скриншоту, у вас на экран влезает 10. Как вы представляете это в виде рабочего инетфейса? Если я не ошибаюсь, вам нужно будет сделать что-то для написания музыки. Смотрели ли вы интерфейсы подобных приложений, например Guitar Pro? Связано ли это с нотной грамотой? Почему 53? Вроде 12 полутонов на октаву всегда было. Как 53 разделить на 12 на цело? Или ваше приложение не будет поддерживать полутоны и никак не связано с обычными нотами? Можете на бумажке нарисовать интерфейс? Что должно происходить, когда юзер что-то нажмет?

Comment: @aepot , почему 53 - https://nashev.livejournal.com/139469.html. Помещается утрированно 10, подогнав правльный размер клавиш чуть больше поместится, а чтобы увидеть их больше - будет масштабирование в k раз. Guitar pro направлен немного в другую сторону, в плане интерфейса тоже. Идея в создании такого несложного(...) гуи - https://imgur.com/a/EBcf1PL. Когда юзер создаёт прямоугольник в правой части - то данная клавиша подписывается на `event` с длительностью воспроизведения равной ширине прямоугольника

Comment: Внесите всё что вы рассказали в текст вопроса.

Comment: Я правильно понял? Слева колонка кнопок, в правой части шкала времени. Жмешь кнопку, напротив нее появляется метка, жмешь следующую, появляется еще одна напротив кнопки, но правее по временной шкале, ну или там, где пользователь поставил на этой шкале курсор. Затем при нажатии кнопки воспроизведения, приложение как музыкальная шкатулка по этим прямоугольникам будет играть мелодию. Осталось понять, как юзер будет длительность и паузы регулировать, и можно будет прикинуть, как сверстать интерфейс. Пока понятно одно - `Grid` вообще не в тему и мимо.

Comment: @aepot , заранее извиняюсь за свою способность отвратительно объяснять что-то и что это проблема мусолится неделю, только учусь. https://imgur.com/a/IbLHZlB - примерно так(набросал в пейнте), зелёные прямоугольники создаются пользователем(по высоте автоматически со строку для это предполагался грид, а длину за край можно регулировать(плохая попытка с `GridSplitter`)) - мышкой с точки X до Y. А их длина определяет длительность звука

Comment: С воспроизведением порядка наставленных прямоугольников пока не придумал реализацию. Ведь они могут быть в разнобой наставлены, но до́лжно как музыкальная шкатулка своими зубцами цеплять бугорки по очереди - те что левее раньше правее - позже(пример)

Comment: Вашу задачу можно разбить на две. Первая - это налепить строк в окно, слева кнопка, справа пусто. А вторая часть - реализовать ползающие прямоугольники справа, что никак не конфликтует с первой частью. Это два совершенно разных вопроса, которые физически не влезут в один ответ.

Comment: @aepot >"Первая - это налепить строк в окно, слева кнопка, справа пусто". Вопрос данной страницы и звучит как "Создание строк кодом C#")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать `ItemsControl`, засунуть его в `ScrollViwer`, и привязать к коллекции.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WPF Window" Height="600" Width="1000" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Background="LightGray">
                                <TextBlock Padding="10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush>
                                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 4" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                                                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    </VisualBrush>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Sounds}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="{Binding Length}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Canvas Background="AliceBlue" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Start}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<RowData> _rows;

    public ObservableCollection<RowData> Rows
    {
        get => _rows;
        set
        {
            _rows = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<RowData>();
            
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            Rows.Add(new RowData()
            {
                Title = "Item" + i,
                Sounds = new ObservableCollection<SoundSquare>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(j => new SoundSquare() { Start = j * 80 + (i % 2 * 40), Length = rnd.Next(80) }))
            });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

```cs
public class RowData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SoundSquare> Sounds { get; set; }
}

public class SoundSquare
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже не знаю почему, но создаётся просто белый экран

Comment: @IgnisDivine `DataContext = this;` и `Loaded="Window_Loaded"` не забыли?

Comment: Теперь да, понял что куда добавить, спасибо. Впереди ещё столько всего учить)

Comment: @IgnisDivine подсказка, куда копать, создайте в классе `RowData` коллекцию из классов данных для прямоугольника, внутри может быть например его горизонтальная координата и ширина. И внутрь воткните еще один `ItemsControl`, который будет вам отвечать за прямоугольники. Грубо говоря, намножить прямоугольников в строке можно точно таким же образом, как уже намножили строк. Это просто, насколько мне известно. Вся сложность будет изменении размера и положения прямоугольника. Копать в сторону контрола под названием `Adorner`. Но сразу предупреждаю, он хитровывитый.

Comment: @IgnisDivine чтобы сделать внутренний `ItemsControl` горизонтальным, добавьте ему `<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel><ItemsPanelTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/></ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>`.

Comment: А можно ли прибиндить уникальный канвас к каждой своей строке в правой части? Для первой строки просто биндился же текст

Comment: @IgnisDivine Да, вы же внутри айтемсконтрола верстаете одну строчку, ее шаблон. Что хотите, то и добавляйте туда. Все что вы туда добавите, будпт повторяться в каждой строке.

Comment: а существует альтернатива `CallerMemberName` и `PropertyChangedEventHandler`? Потому что они же работают только со `string`, что под `Canvas` не подходит

Comment: @IgnisDivine вы говорите про 2 совершенно никак не связанные между собой вещи. `[CallerMemberName]` - это автоматическая подстановка названия свойства, в данном случае `Rows` на основании того, откуда метод `OnPropertyChanged()` был вызван. Если убрать этот аттрибут, то придется вызывать с аргументом `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Rows))`. То есть он для удобства только.

Comment: @IgnisDivine https://habr.com/ru/post/427325/ вот здесь автор вроде дело рассказывает, но не использует аттрибут `[CallerMemberName]`. https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.2.php вот здесь про то же самое, но другими словами. Поищите и почитайте еще.

Comment: Хабровская статья хорошая, спасибо, разобрался немного что на что влияет, но `PropertyChangedEventArgs`, работает только со `string` https://imgur.com/a/0g8DsFQ . На английском стэке нашёл такую реализацию добавления `Canvas` https://imgur.com/a/rNqlr3M

Comment: Вам просто надо добавить вызов `set { _canvas = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }`, а сам метод `OnPropertyChanged` оставьте в том виде, в котором я вам его дал. Вам нужно в метод имя Свойства передавать - `"ShowCanvas"`, но это сделает за вас `[CallerMemberName]`, просто добавить вызов метода `OnPropertyChanged()` в сеттер свойства. Всё. Биндинг, увидит событие и сам заберет данные из свойства. Понимаете фокус? Не вы отправляете данные в интерфейс, он их забирает сам. Вы сообщаете интерфейсу `у меня изменилось свойство "ShowCanvas"!`, а там сидят подписанные на событие `PropertyChanged` биндинги

Comment: @IgnisDivine ...и сравнивают строчку, которая `propertyName` с тем что вы написали в xaml. То есть `Text="{Binding MyText}"` означает что как вы только вызовите `OnPropertyChanged("MyText")` (`"MyText"` - тоже самое что `nameof(MyText)`, просто для рефакторинга удобнее), биндинг тут же придет к вам в класс, заберет данные из свойства `MyText`, и сразу же засунет их в контрол, в котором вы его объявили. Еще чуть-чуть поразбираетесь, и поймете, насколько же это просто.

Comment: Ну не думаю что всё так просто), но ваши объяснения лучше всякой документации. Однако `Canvas` добавить не вышло по тому же принципу, точнее он просто не появился

Comment: @IgnisDivine если уж на то пошло, вам не нужно добавлять канвас, я вам больше скажу, вам вообще не нужен канвас. Прямоугольник можно с помощью `<Border>` нарисовать. Но и это еще не все, у вас вообще контролов не должно быть в C# коде. В коде должны быть данные. Я вам показал методику, как я рисую кучу серых бордеров, вы видели хоть один бордер в C# коде? А текстблок? Я вам выше написал, создайте класс, хранящий 2 координаты. Засуньте в `RowData` коллекцию `public ObservableCollection SoundData { get; set; }`, похоже на то что я делал с `Rows`? Да! Это я и имел в виду.

Comment: Что ж, это прибавило ещё больше проблем. А как одновременно использовать привязку к 2 листам? `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">` и для `Canvas`. 2 Грида и в каждом свой `ItemsControl ItemsSource`?

Comment: @IgnisDivine обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @IgnisDivine я доработал решение, теперь оно точно работает. Скриншот тоже обновил.