# Динамическое добавление Canvas в строку

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Попытка добавить на каждую строку по `Canvas`, с последующей возможностью его изменения.
Ошибок компиляции нет, и вроде как новый экземпляр `Canvas` присваивается свойству `ShowCanvas` и добавляется в коллекцию `CanvasList` через цикл в методе `Window_Loaded`. На как проверка - изменения цвета, не работает. Наследование `CanvasData` от `Canvas` ни к чему тоже не привело

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Sequencer_2._1._1
{
     public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        private ObservableCollection<RowData> _rows;
        public ObservableCollection<RowData> Rows
        {
            get => _rows;
            set
            {
                _rows = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<CanvasData> _canvasList;
        public ObservableCollection<CanvasData> CanvasList
        {
            get => _canvasList;
            set
            {
                _canvasList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rows = new ObservableCollection<RowData>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
                Rows.Add(new RowData() { Title = "Item" + i });

            CanvasList = new ObservableCollection<CanvasData>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                CanvasList.Add(new CanvasData() { ShowCanvas = new Canvas() });
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                CanvasList[i].ShowCanvas.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
    }
    public class RowData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
    public class CanvasData
    {
        public Canvas ShowCanvas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.xaml Привязка к свойству во 2ом `Border` и 2 колонке

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="LightSlateGray">
                            <TextBlock Padding="10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 4" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"
                                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, 
                                            Path=ActualWidth}"
                                            Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, 
                                            Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                            <Canvas>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path = ShowCanvas}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 4" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"
                                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, 
                                            Path=ActualWidth}"
                                            Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, 
                                            Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что делает каждая строка данного кода? Понимаете, для чего вы допустим вызываете `OnPropertyChanged();`? Или почему тут `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `OnPropertyChanged` оповещает `Binding` о том что свойства `Rows` и `CanvasList` изменились, а `ObservableCollection` работает в связке с первым и оповещает об изменении данных в коллекции?

Comment: Верно, тогда вы сейчас сами ответили на свой вопрос. Взгляните на свойство `ShowCanvas` и скажите что не так.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ но он же не ссылается на данные как другие свойства, и для `OnPropertyChanged` же необходимы данные на вход

Comment: `ShowCanvas = new Canvas()` - это создание нового объекта и если вы такое сделаете с привязанным свойством, то UI это изменение не увидит. Другими словами, если вы делаете изменение привязанного свойства через код, то оно обязано вызывать INPC. Но у вас тут проблема не только в этом. Вот у вас есть `CanvasList`, ок, но где хоть одно взаимодействие с ним? В XAML я его не вижу, какой либо связи в C# тоже нету, лишь заполнение, но зато в XAML я вижу `Binding ShowCanvas`, хотя привязана коллекция `Rows`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , можно ли как-нибудь привязать `CanvasList` параллельно с `Rows`? `CanvasList` же по идее уже заполнен пустыми `Canvas` в части `ViewModel`

Comment: 2 нижних `Grid` в основном в каждом по своей реализации - `ItemsControl` для `Canvas` и `Rows`?

Comment: Начнем наверно с того, что у вас весьма странная структура, ибо 1. В WPF вы не должны содержать UI контролы в коде, ибо это попросту лишнее. Сделайте класс, который будет описывать нужный вам канвас и его привязывайте. 2. Вам не кажется странном, что вы делаете класс `CanvasData`, а затем внутри еще `Canvas`? Почему тогда сразу не сделать `Canvas`?

Comment: Также, вы должны определить связь между объектами. Вот давайте предположим, что у вас задача, это сделать вывод кошельков для хранения денег, вы сейчас имеете отдельно допусти 10 кошельков и отдельно мешок с деньгами, они попросту не связаны как либо друг с другом. Но вы можете допустим распределить этот мешек с деньгами по кошелькам, тогда у вас каждый кошелек будет сожержать некую сумму денег. Вот также и тут, вы можете сделать коллекцию канвасов внутри каждого Row, тогда у вас будет связать, вы будете знать что Row1 содержит в себе допустим 5 канвасов.

Comment: А в XAML вы `ContentPresenter` меняете на еще один `ItemsControl` или любой другой элемент, который выводит данные. НО, я честно, без понятия как тогда в таком случае потом вам делать нужное перетаскивание и так далее...

Comment: [Вот здесь я доработал и опубликовал решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214837/373567). Суть в том, что работать с канвасами из кода не нужно, с канвасами работает вложенный `ItemsControl`, вместо этого из кода работать нужно только с координатами прямоугольников.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , всё, понял, спасибо