# Нужна помощь в выборе графического инструмента для WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, диаграммы

Нужна помощь в выборе графического инструмента для WPF для решения следующей задачи.

Нужно визуализировать 3-х слойную модель:

- 1 слой представляет собой сечение объекта, (квадраты с разными свойствами) размеры естественно разные 100х100м или 2000х500м, делается в любом чарте, тут проблем нет.
- 2-й слой представляет собой несколько прямоугольников, в качестве заливки - изображение (то есть поддержка кистей виндовс ImageBrach. тайлы - небольшие bmp файлы) ещё нужно эти прямоугольники вращать на произвольны угол, при этом форма и заливка не должны искажаться при изменении масштабирования нижнего слоя.

Сделал на канве, но не понимаю как совместить с нижним чартом, например ось х на отметке 300м - такой прямоугольник. изменили размеры графика на чарте - отметка 300м естественно сместилась, как отследить куда надо передвинуть/перерисовать прямоугольник. Опять же длинна прямоугольников должна меняться в зависимости от масштаба по оси Y, а ширина оставаться постоянной.

3-й слой нужен интерактивный, то есть дать возможность мышкой нарисовать некую область и нужно иметь возможность изменить свойства квадратов из 1-го слоя, попавших в нарисованную область (например закрасить их одним цветом). Так же нужно иметь возможность передвинуть границу области (мышкой сместить точку у у серии типа полилайн).

Для рисования на canvas например, есть куча примеров, но та же проблема - совместить с чартом.
В данный момент частично реализовано на LiveChart, есть проблемы:
Не смог получить доступ к отдельной LineSeries в коллекции для поворота. Пересчитываю координаты точек объектов и перерисовываю их. При этом тайлы искажаются при изменении масштаба по оси Y прямоугольники 2-го слоя искажаются.

Не могу найти, можно ли рисовать на самом LiveChart ? или единственный вариант отслеживать мышь на области графика и например по щелчку добавлять точки в серию на чарте?

До этого пробовал OxyPlot, но он не имеет поддержки кистей виндовс.
Вроде можно всё сделать на канве, но не понимаю как быть с масштабированием - пересчитывать размеры всего в ручную? (при изменении размеров окна или среза объекта), использование LiveChart не принципиально, а WPF обязательно.

Может всё таки есть инструмент, который позволит всё это сделать ?
Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Скриншот существующей программы (не моей). мне надо сделать что то подобное

[image]

Прямоугольники имеют одинаковую заливку, но при этом у повёрнутых она искажена.

Comment: Вопрос для людей с мощным воображением? Проиллюстрируйте его картинками и фрагментами кода.

Comment: Перечитал раз 10 ваш вопрос, но конкретную проблему понять не могу, ну кроме того, что вы не можете справиться с задачей с использованием существующих инструментов. Но чтобы найти конкретное решение, надо пробовать реализовывать вашу задачу на стороне отвечающего, то есть писать весь ваш код с нуля. Как минимум потому что вы ни строчки кода не показали. Этим, скорее всего, заниматься никто не будет. На этот вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ. Можно ответить даже "используюй Unity" или "рисуй графики сам и учи геометрию", и оба в будут правильные в отношении к изложенному выше вопросу.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда более конкретный вопрос. Как можно установить canvas в точку 0 осей LiveChart ?  или любой другой точки на оси ?  то есть нарисовать любую фигуру в определённой точке на чарте ? это возможно ? (например точка имеет относительные координаты в масштабе чарта (3000;1000) нужно узнать соответствующие координаты панели на которой размещены и чарт и канвас (он сверху). Спасибо.

Comment: (не успел отредактировать) И нужно обратное действие - нарисовав линию на канве поверх чарта - узнать её координаты в системе координат чарта. Если сможете подсказать с этим, тогда собственно весь вопрос и решится. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы работали с привязкой данных? Если да, тогда должны догадаться, что вам нужна коллекция точек, например `ObservableCollection<Point>` и `ItemsControl` с панелью типа `Canvas` ([вот я делал что-то похожее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214837/373567), смотреть вложенный айтемсконтрол). Координаты в коллекции можете задавать хоть в попугаях, главное понимать, как их пересчитать на реальные координаты в канвасах. Далее вяжете элемент `ItemsContol`а через `MultiBinding` и `IMultiValueConverter` к этой коллекции, передавая в конвертер свойства для пересчета координат. И готово.

Comment: "Координаты в коллекции можете задавать хоть в попугаях, главное понимать,как их пересчитать на реальные координаты в канвасах" - мне нужна как раз подсказка по этому вопросу. Модель данных с коллекциями элементов есть. по биндингам и прочему помощь не нужна, всё реализовано.

Comment: Вам формулу пересчета вывести надо, или найти место, где ее воткнуть? Если первое, то не понятно, как. Если второе, то про конвертер я выше написал.

Comment: Первое, я уже понял что готовых решений нет, видимо надо выводить наружу размерности чарта (max по X и Y) и пересчитывать относительно размеров родительской панели. и ещё вызывать пересчёт координат при изменении размеров окна. Но всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, может кому пригодится.

У LiveChart есть методы `ConvertToChartValues` и `ConvertToPixels` (https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wpf/LiveCharts-Wpf-Extentions)

```
Point Nxy = new Point(0,0); //точка начала осей чарта
Point Nxy1 = Chart1.ConvertToPixels(Nxy); //координаты этой точки в пикселях контейнера
Polygon reg = new Polygon();
reg.Points.Add(Nxy1);
reg.Points.Add(new Point(Nxy1.X+ 400, 100));
reg.Points.Add(new Point(Nxy1.X + 400, 200));

reg.Points.Add(Nxy1);
reg.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
reg.Name = "reg1";
canva.Children.Add(reg);
```

Данный код даёт координаты точки начала осей в пикселях. Нарисованный на канве полигон включает эту точку. Главное изначально точно совместить канву и чарт.

[image: полученный результат]