# Как сделать генерацию сетки в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть вот такая сетка

```
        <ScrollViewer Margin="126,0,0,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid Height="1182">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,-16,0">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="130*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="130*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="130*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="107"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="107"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="107"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="5">
                        <Grid/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="130"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на этом гриде есть скролвювер, как сделать чтобы такая же сетка генерировалась внизу

Comment: А смысл задачи то в чем? Какую цель вы преследуете? Зачем это нужно?

Comment: @aepot ну в этих квадратах будут блоки с кнопкой и картинкой

Comment: Откуда они возьмутся? Давайте вы сразу все расскажете от начала и до конца, чтобы можно было решение реализовать, а не по крупицам информацию вытягивать. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Есть  джсон в котором есть количество блоков название и другая информация, я не думал что это важно

Comment: Вы пошли задачу решать не тем путем, совсем не тем. Давайте конкретный json текстом в пост и ожидаемый результат, еще расскажите, почему у окна именно такие отступы, потому что пиксельные отступы таким образом - тоже неверный подход. Этот интерфейс развалится при первом же изменении DPI монитора.

Comment: @aepot Вопрос не в том что при первом же изменении DPI монитора интерфейс развалится, а в том как динамически генерировать сетку\

Comment: Не, вы меня не поняли, зачем генерировать сетку, которая развалится? Наверное надо рабочее решение, а не люое первое попавшееся, так? Сейчас накидаю пример.

Comment: @aepot А как лучше сделать чтобы она не развалилась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для презентации коллекций в интерфейсе есть контролы для коллекций - ListView, ListBox, и другие. И самый простой и базовый из них - ItemsControl.

Не используйте отступы для позиционирования, используйте их только для отступов.

Проще всего сделать этот фокус с помощью привязки данных и `ItemsControl`.

Пусть класс данных будет такой.

```cs
public class DataItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Чтобы незаморачивать вас реализацией интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`, я создам свойство только для чтения, в нем будет жить коллекция данных. `ObservableCollection` - то же самое что и `List`, только интерфейс умеет ослеживать в ней изменения.

```cs
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add(new DataItem { Name = "Hello" });
    }
}
```

```xml
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="130"/>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="20,0">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid Width="130" Height="107">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                       <!-- здесь сделайте разметку ячейки -->
                   </Grid>
               <DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <WrapPanel/>
                   <!-- та самая панель, которая автоматом переносит лишние элементы на новую строчку -->
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

При добавлении и удалении элементов в коллекции `Items` они автоматически будут появляться и удаляться из интерфейса в режиме реального времени.

Свойство `Items` нельзя переприсвоить, если это мешает, реализуйте `INotifyPropertyChanged`, это я показывал много раз ранее, например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214837/373567).

Помимо `WrapPanel` есть еще `StackPanel`, `UniformGrid`, `DockPanel` и другие менее популярные панели, познакомьтесь с ними.

Comment: Спасибо большое!