# В чем может быть причина ошибки при работе с классом Graphics

Tags: c#, ооп, графика

Есть следующий код:

```
try
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(image_name));
            if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            YoloV4Prediction predict;
            lock (_predictionEngine)
            {
                predict = _predictionEngine.Predict(new YoloV4BitmapData() { Image = bitmap });
            }
            if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            _handleOneAB = new ActionBlock<YoloV4Result>((res) => {
                //Записать результат, если нужно
                var x1 = res.BBox[0];
                var y1 = res.BBox[1];
                var x2 = res.BBox[2];
                var y2 = res.BBox[3];
                lock (bitmap)
                {
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
                        using (var brushes = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red)))
                        {
                            g.FillRectangle(brushes, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
                        }
                        g.DrawString(res.Label + " " + res.Confidence.ToString("0.00"),
                                             new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Blue, new PointF(x1, y1));
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        bitmap.Save(image_name + "WithRectangles.jpg");
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
                //Вывести результат на экран:
                UI.OutputFunc(res, image_name);
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
            });
```

В силу непонятных причин иногда выскакивает ошибка "parameter is not valid" при вызове конструктора класса Graphics. В чем может быть ошибка? Что интересно, на одном ноутбуке ошибок нет никогда, а на другом - иногда бывает

Comment: Показанного кода недостаточно для выявления проблемы. Выглядит нормально, в смысле я бы тут кое-что оптимизировал, но источников для указанного исключения не вижу.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, добавил внешний код

Comment: А что если не через lock, а сделать перенаправление в поток, где этот битмап создан? Могу пример показать. Кстати, `_handleOneAB` - это что, где оно определено, где оно используется? Почему именно вы выбрали DataFlow? В общем, понятнее не стало, но есть подозрение, что битмап "занят" во время вызова `ActionBlock`. Это проблема типа Race Condition, когда один поток непредсказуемо обгоняет другой. Но опять же этого кода снова недостаточно, чтобы наверняка понять. :)

Comment: Это Winforms, WPF? Контекст синхронизации есть?

Comment: Это WPF, контекста нет

Comment: Если это WPF, значит UI контекст как минимум есть. Вы правда не показали, как оно запускается, из UI или из рабочего потока. Просто если есть контекст синхронизации, и битмап создается там, то вместо лока лучше завернуть рисование обратно в UI поток. Это лучше, чем дергать мониторы.

Comment: О, кажется дошло `UI.OutputFunc(res, image_name);` - это же отдание битмапа в UI, так? То есть вы интерфейсу битмап отдаете раньше, чем он отрисуется? То есть интерфейс делает LickBits для его отрисовки и вы в этот же момент в другом потоке пытаетесь достать из залоченного битмапа Graphics. Вот и получается, то что получается. Race Condition, кто успел тот и съел. Вам нужно дождаться, когда предсказалка отработает до конца и только потом отдавать битмап интерфейсу. А еще вы пытаетесь отданный битмап еще и на диск писать. Зачем? Давайте больше кода.

Comment: Кстати, если это WPF, зачем вы вообще на битмапе рисуете? Создайте `ObservableCollection` c координатами, привяжите к ней ItemsControl с панелью Canvas и рисуйте прямо поверх картинки прямоугольники Rectangle в интерфейсе. И графикс вообще станет не нужен. Запустили распознавалку кадра, собрали все прямоугольники из нее, отдали кадр в интерфейс вместе с координатами прямоугольников, а UI отрисует все что надо. Хотя в вашем случае даже обычный List или массив подойдет.

Comment: А где можно почитать про отрисовку прямо в интерфесе?Делаю так просто потому что иначе не знаю как делать

Comment: Не совсем то что вам нужно, но методика превращения координат в прямоугольник там есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214837/373567

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Подскажу, чтобы абсолютный реальный размер канваса, который должен быть как у кадра преобразовать в видимый размер, создайте канвас размером с кадр в пикселях и засуньте его во ViewBox, которая его уже отресайзит.

Answer (score 0):

Если выскакивает иногда и в основном на больших изображениях то предположу такой ответ.

Ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333718/12888024).

Имейте в виду, что это LOT памяти, которую вы пытаетесь выделить с помощью этого Bitmap.

См . [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Форумы/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/37684999-62c7-4c41-8167-745a2b486583/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/37684999-62c7-4c41-8167-745a2b486583/)

.NET, скорее всего, откажется создавать образ, который одновременно использует столько непрерывной памяти.

Немного сложнее читать, но эта ссылка также помогает:

[http://www.tech-archive.net/Архив/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.drawing/2005-06/msg00176.html](http://www.tech-archive.net/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.drawing/2005-06/msg00176.html)

Каждый образ в системе имеет объем памяти, определяемый этой формулой: bit-depth * width * height / 8 Это означает, что для изображения размером 40800 пикселей на 4050 потребуется более 660 мегабайт памяти.

Comment: Я видел это, там ошибка при создании объекта Bitmap, а у меня - при создании объекта класса Graphics

Comment: @MathSamurai а память вам не нужна там что-ли?